# Uniform convergence of $(1+x) \log \frac{1+n+nx}{n+e^{-x}}$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(f_n)_{n \ge 1} \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions given by 
$$f_n(x)=(1+x) \log \frac{1+n+nx}{n+e^{-x}},$$
fo all $x\in [0,1], n \ge 1$. Does $(f_n)_{n \ge 1}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Well, it's easy to see that the given sequence converges pointwisely to $f\colon[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=(1+x) \log (1+x),$ $\forall x \in [0,1]$.

Now, it remains to study $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\sup\limits_{ x \in [0,1] }\left| f_n(x)-f(x) \right| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\sup\limits_{ x \in [0,1] }\left| (1+x) \log \frac{1+n+nx}{(1+x)(n+e^{-x})} \right|$.

If we denote $g_n(x)=(1+x) \log \frac{1+n+nx}{(1+x)(n+e^{-x})}$, we have:
$$ g'_n(x)= \log \frac{1+n+nx}{(1+x)(n+e^{-x})} - \frac{1}{1+n+nx}+\frac{1+x}{ne^x+1}, $$
but this doesn't help me! Can anyone tell me what should I do next? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if your sequence is increasing, but if the answer is yes, check the Dini's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

Comment: Thank you! The theorem can be used because the given sequence is decreasing!